View doesn't update if Source Array is updated
Imagine you have a struct like
struct TheObject: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
}

Now you store an array of that type inside a ViewModel
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title")]
}

You create a NavigationLink for each item of objects. Those NavigationLinks feature a button, which replaces the objects array with the same object (by id) but a different property
 @StateObject var model = Model()

 NavigationStack {
     List(model.objects) { object in
         NavigationLink("Text", value: object)
     }
     .navigationDestination(for: TheObject.self) { object in
         Text(object.title)
             .onTapGesture {
                 model.objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title changed")]
             }
     }
 }

What did I expect to happen?
I expected my opened NavigationLink to be updated with the new title.
What did I get instead?
The view did not change. Instead I have to pop the view and reopen it to reveal the changes.
How can I get my expected behavior to work and why does it currently behave like that?

looks like you forgot the List

True, but that is unrelated to the issue, unfortunately

maybe you are missing @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

That's also not it. I would get a compiler error in this example. I will go ahead and add those details, so that it gets more clear.

When you use Text(object.title) the passed in object is a let and is not
observed for changes by the view, so it will not change when you change the model
in the onTapGesture.
But the view will change if you use the model (that is observed for changes),
as shown in the example code.
struct TheObject: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(model.objects) { object in
                NavigationLink(object.title, value: object) // <--- for testing
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: TheObject.self) { object in
                if let obj = model.objects.first(where: {$0.id == object.id}) {
                    Text(obj.title) // <--- here
                        .onTapGesture {
                            model.objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title changed")]
                        }
                }

            // alternative
//                if let ndx = model.objects.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == object.id}) {
//                    Text(model.objects[ndx].title)
//                        .onTapGesture {
//                            model.objects[ndx].title = "title changed"
//                        }
//                }


            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
An alternative to achieve what you want, is to use Observable,
the more robust replacement of ObservableObject class.
For example:
@Observable class TheObject: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    static func == (lhs: TheObject, rhs: TheObject) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
          hasher.combine(id)
          hasher.combine(title)
      }
    
    var id: String
    var title: String
    
    init(id: String, title: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}

@Observable class Model {
    var objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(model.objects) { object in
                NavigationLink(object.title, value: object)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: TheObject.self) { object in
                Text(object.title)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        object.title = "title changed"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


Your solution works great! However I use Codable Structs with Firebase so I guess @Observableis out of question for me. Maybe helpful for others stumbling upon this.
Beside all that I wonder why I even need to use this "workaround". I thought conforming to Equatable and Hashable by only using id would do the job, which it didn't. Would you mind elaborating that?

Sorry but I don't understand your questions,
...why I even need to use this "workaround"..., what "workaround" are
you referring to. Similarly, what do you mean by ...using id would do the job, which it didn't.

By workaround I mean using the first(where: ) statement instead of accessing it directly.
I identify TheObject through, and only through, the ID. I expected the compiler to interpret the updated TheObject as the "old" one but with a changed property (and then show the change). At least this should happen when I implement Equatable to just check the equality of the ID property. Basically my question is: Why does it think it is a different object?

The object in the navigationDestination is only a copy of
an immutable struct TheObject. It is a let, it cannot be changed.
To change a model you need to refer to the original one in class Model: ObservableObject....
Because these are being observed by the view when you declare
@StateObject private var model = Model(). To refer to that original
object use its id to find it. This is not a workaround, it is normal.
See  Monitoring data for how to manage data in your app.

Thank you for your clarification, I appreciate it!

The reason your Text View isn't updating is that object is passed to the closure as a copy, it's not the same instance of model. To display the mutated value, you would have to pass the same instance of model to the Text View like so:
 .navigationDestination(for: TheObject.self) { _ in
            Text(model.objects[0].title)
                .onTapGesture {
                    model.objects = [TheObject(id: "id", title: "title changed")]
                }
        }


Thanks for your reply. In my actual app I fetch the mode.objects from my cloud, which is why I need to replace the whole array. Also there might me more than one value inside the array.
